# Верстка шаблона вордпресс

Tags: html, wordpress, css

Как верстать шаблоны вордпресс? Я вообще запутался, какими файлами работать? index и стилями, а другими файлами что делать сайдбаром, хэдэром и т.д

Answer (score 4):

Создание шаблона WP состоит из нескольких этапов:

1. Создание дизайна
2. Верстка
3. Добавление динамических элементов WP

Для начала само собой нужно сделать html страницы с дизайном. Хотя бы для двух страниц: главная и страница статьи.

Думаю первые два этапа не нужно объяснять как делать :)

В WP есть ряд динамических штук, которые позволяют делать шаблоны. Для того, что бы понять как делать wp шаблоны лучше всего покапаться в коде уже созданных.

Основные файлы:

- index.php
- style.css
- single.php

Можно еще выделить часто используемые части в отдельный файл:

- header.php
- footer.php
- sidebar.php

Но самый просто шаблон можно сделать используя только основные файлы :)

Я начинал изучать создание шаблонов wp с того, что брал готовый шаблон и переделывал его под свои нужны, тем самым через некоторое время хорошо разобрался в структуре и теперь спокойно делаю шаблоны с нуля.

Желаю удачи, в этом увлекательном деле!

Answer (score 0):

Обязательными файлами в шаблоне являются index.php и style.css, остальные облегчают вставку повторяющегося кода.

Например, у нас есть "шапка" сайта, вырезаем ее в header.php, а в index.php на месте шапки пишем `get_header()`, index.php будет использоваться для всех страниц.

Будет полезным изучение [иерархии шаблонов в WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2)